# Create a Template showing pending invoice amounts

Tags: contributions, invoice, pending

I have set up a search that shows all 30 day, 60 day and 90 day outstanding memberships.  I can then email those that I want from the list of members.

Is there a way to create a mailing template that will show all their pending contribution payments.

I don't want to set up scheduled reminders because we need an element of control over which of those members we send to but I don't want to manually send to each to give them a summary of what they owe.

Civicrm 3.53 and wordpress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a custom token may be a possible solution. [Fuzion Tokens](https://civicrm.org/extensions/fuzion-tokens) has some pending contribution tokens that sound close to what you want, but your case seems a little more complicated because it involves multiple pending contributions. You might be able to build on (or hire someone to build on) the next pending contribution token from Fuzion Tokens.